Locator visibility timeouts when scraping hotel search results
My updated code after incorporating feedback (I specified different HTML class for some fields because the output I got did not look quite right:
import json
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


with sync_playwright() as pw:
    browser = pw.firefox.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?adults=2&allowPreAppliedFilters=false&children=&d1=2024-06-21&d2=2024-06-23&destination=Venice%20%28and%20vicinity%29%2C%20Veneto%2C%20Italy&flexibility=6_DAY_LOWER&flexibility=7_DAY_UPPER&flexibleSearchRequirement=INCLUDE_WEEKEND&latLong=45.434031%2C12.338332&mapBounds=&regionId=179981&rooms=1&searchRange=2024-07-01_2024-07-31&semdtl=&sort=RECOMMENDED&stay_options_group=hotels_option&theme=&useRewards=false&userIntent=")
    show_more = page.locator("button", has_text="Show More")

    while show_more.is_visible():
        try:
            show_more.click()
        except:
            break
        time.sleep(2)

    hotels = page.locator('[data-stid="lodging-card-responsive"]').evaluate_all("""
        els => els.map(el => {
          const text = s => el.querySelector(s)?.textContent.trim();
          return {
            hotel_name: text("h3.uitk-heading"),
            location: text("div.uitk-type-300"),
            rating: text("span.uitk-badge-base-text"),
            price: text("div.uitk-type-500"),
            total_price: text("div.uitk-type-200"),
          };
        })
    """)
    print(json.dumps(hotels, indent=2))
    browser.close()

After running this modified code, I got a new error which is:
raise rewrite_error(error, f"{parsed_st['apiName']}: {error}") from None
playwright._impl._errors.Error: Locator.evaluate_all: missing } after property list
evaluate@debugger eval code:226:30
@debugger eval code:1:44

I would expect the output to look like this (screenshot attached):


Locators check visibility, but you don't care about visibility--you just want the data. For scraping, you don't always need to use locators. They're more of a testing tool.
Since you already waited for the top-level cards to exist, all the data you want will be rendered, and you can pull it directly with JS, disregarding visibility and actionability:
import json
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.44.0


with sync_playwright() as pw:
    browser = pw.firefox.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("<Your URL>")
    show_more = page.locator("button", has_text="Show More")

    while show_more.is_visible():
        try:
            show_more.click()
        except:
            break
        time.sleep(2)

    hotels = page.locator('[data-stid="lodging-card-responsive"]').evaluate_all("""
        els => els.map(el => {
          const text = s => el.querySelector(s)?.textContent.trim();
          return {
            hotel_name: text("h3.uitk-heading"),
            location: text("div.uitk-type-300"),
            rating: text("span.uitk-badge-base-text"),
            price: text("div.uitk-type-500")?.replace(/[$,]/g, ""),
            total_price: text(
              '[data-test-id="price-summary-message-line"]:nth-child(2)'
            )
              ?.replace(" total", "").replace(/[$,]/g, ""),
          };
        })
    """)
    print(json.dumps(hotels, indent=2))
    browser.close()

Granted, this is a bit hacky, just a quick fix. A better approach is probably to intercept the GraphQL response and avoid their rather nasty-looking DOM.
If you want a CSV, the easiest way is:
import pandas # 2.2.2

pandas.DataFrame(hotels).to_csv("hotels.csv", index=False)

I'd also block images, fonts, stylesheets and anything else not necessary for the data. This will speed things up a bit.

My output looks fine for the hotel_name and price but the location, rating, and total_price don’t look quite right. For example, outputs for Baglioni Hotel Luna(location, rating, total_price) are "Superior Room", “Ad", "The price was $1,345$1,345The price is $720$720”. I would expect the output to look like this: “San Marco”, “9.2”, $4819”, and I want rating, price, and total_price to be integer or a float type. Would it be possible in this case? I also played around and changed HTML class for these fields but I run into errors...

Yeah, the classes and DOM on this page are weird, which is partially why I mentioned this was a bit hacky. The point of the answer is to show a better pattern for scraping the data, not optimizing your selectors. I couldn't find an obvious way to get that clearly better-looking output after a few minutes of fussing, and I don't have time to look at this further at the moment, so I'd intercept the GraphQL requests as suggested in any case, which will provide all the raw data without formatting, avoiding the DOM entirely.

Here’s the errors I got: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 514, in wrap_api_call     raise rewrite_error(error, f"{parsed_st['apiName']}: {error}") from None playwright._impl._errors.Error: Locator.evaluate_all: missing } after property list evaluate@debugger eval code:226:30 @debugger eval code:1:44, after specifying different class for the 3 fields I mentioned. At this rate, I guess I can play around with GraphQL in Python then.

I guess I can use GraphQL in my Python script instead of using Playwright package?

No, you would still use Playwright. I'd use page.on("response", ... or expect_response to capture responses as they come into the browser as you scroll the page. Whichever URLs match the GraphQL endpoint can be stored as a dictionary. If I have time I'll update my answer later.

As a workaround in the meantime, you can use int(re.search(r"\$(\d+)", x)[1]) to pull a value from a price string and convert it to an integer 101. Although generally converting floats should be avoided--multiply them to pennies to avoid weird rounding behavior, depending on what you want to do with the data. [int(x) for x in re.findall(r"\$(\d+)", val)] gives you all of the dollar chunks. use ([\d.]+) if you want to include decimals.

I see. So I will add something like this for the Rating field: Rating: int(re.search(r"\$(\d+)", x)[1])("div.uitk-type-500”).

No, I think I'm just confusing you, sorry. re.search's second argument is just a primitive value. Maybe use ChatGPT to do it--show it the current list/dict data structure and ask it to give you code to get the one you want. You can also do the regex work in the browser.

As for Location and Total_Price fields, I am still figuring out how to get the correct HTML class to pull expected data.

Thanks. I updated the selectors a bit, should be more accurate, if still a bit hacky since the page is a hot mess. If you want to keep the $ and , then remove the .replace() calls. If you want numbers, add + before the text() calls. If you want a CSV, you can use Pandas or the builtin CSV writer. You can optionally filter out nulls since a number of records are ads or otherwise incomplete.

Thanks so much. I will test it out as soon as I can and will reach out to you if I have questions.

I tested it out and it works nicely for me. I have a few questions I’d like to ask you. For the total_price, we don’t specify the class? Because I saw that it has data-test-id and I wonder what does nth-child(2) do? Also, some cards are Ads but they do have rating, like Baglioni Hotel with a rating of 9.2 but it is null in the output. Is there any chance I could modify it so that it can show the rating? For the first card, same hotel, I noticed that the Superior Room and San Marco have same div class, but the output only shows Superior Room. Can I make it show San Marco as well?

Sure, add the selector for the ad rating as a comma: .foo, .bar matches .foo first and if it can't find it, tries .bar. Test ids are more stable than the CSS classes here--like I said, the site is a wreck, all manner of missing, inconsistent data, hidden and no good classes or hooks to use to select elements. nth-child(2) selects the second child--not good practice but it's the best I could do given limited time and a mess of a site. I need to stop here because this answers your primary issue and gets you in the ballpark. Maybe open a new question if you have ongoing issues.

I think I’m good with this for now. I’ll open new question if I encounter new issues. Thanks.
